# how to initialize a bouncycastle BigInteger?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, biginteger

the hex string is correctly parsed into bytes, its values are [0]0xf4, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR0q1.png)0xd0,[2]0x93,[3]0xb2...... i used the bytes to initialize a bouncycastle BigInteger. i expect its magnitude value is [0]0xf4d093b2, ....... what is the right method to initialize it? thanks.

```
string hex= "f4d093b25d690053d1fcc36d3b0278b89565af2d8dac1afa05837336365cc197";
byte[] bytes = hexEncoder.DecodeData(hex);
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, bytes);